# Notepad++ work space project using server directory

Tags: notepad++

I have a notepad++ workspace with a project, when i right click the project it gives me "Add files from directory", which is great for local files.

But I am logged in via notepad's FTP plugin called **nppFTP** and want to use a directory from the server I am connected to in my work space project.

The work space i refer to is this shown in image:

[image]

Is there any way to do this? Perhaps, a plugin or setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sshfs tool

http://igikorn.com/sshfs-windows-8/
it will create you a local folder of a remote folder. This local folder will be usable by notepad++ as any folder